# Problems regarding nagios.cfg with defined services and hosts (generated by Nagiosql)

Tags: nagios

Nagiosql generated files make problems during preflight check - but everythings seems to be okay.

/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg

```
....
## Hosts
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/hosts/
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/hosttemplates.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/hostgroups.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/hostextinfo.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/hostescalations.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/hostdependencies.cfg
## Services
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/services/
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/servicetemplates.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/servicegroups.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/serviceextinfo.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/serviceescalations.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagiosql/servicedependencies.cfg
...
```

nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg

```
....
Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking services...
Error: There are no services defined!
        Checked 0 services.
Checking hosts...
Error: There are no hosts defined!
        Checked 0 hosts.
```

The content seems okay to me

```
[root@xxx services]# cd /etc/nagiosql/services/
[root@xxx services]# ls -alh
total 20K
drwsr-sr-x 2 apache nagios 4.0K Aug  7 10:46 .
drwsr-sr-x 5 apache nagios 4.0K Aug  7 12:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache nagios 2.3K Aug  7 10:46 localhost.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache nagios 2.2K Aug  7 10:46 www.google.com.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache nagios 1.1K Aug  7 10:46 www.yahoo.com.cfg

[root@xxx hosts]# ls -alh
total 16K
drwsr-sr-x 2 apache nagios 4.0K Aug 11 07:12 .
drwsr-sr-x 5 apache nagios 4.0K Aug  7 12:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache nagios  800 Aug 11 07:12 GIT.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache nagios  948 Aug 11 07:12 psm01.cfg
```

Content also seems to be fine (generated by nagiosql):

```
[root@xxx hosts]# vi GIT.cfg
###############################################################################
#
# Host configuration file
#
# Created by: Nagios QL Version 3.2.0
# Date:       2015-08-11 07:12:54
# Version:    Nagios 3.x config file
#
# --- DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND ---
# Nagios QL will overwite all manual settings during the next update
#
###############################################################################

define host {
        host_name                       GIT
        alias                           GIT Server
        address                         172.25.10.80
        register                        0
}

###############################################################################
#
# Host configuration file
#
# END OF FILE
#
###############################################################################
~
```

Can somebody tell me where the solution for this problem is? Already wasted 2 hours...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the final **slash** from the directory names in your `cfg_dir` definitions and see if that doesn´t get it to recognize the cfg files in that directory.

For example,

Change:

```
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/hosts/
...
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/services/
```

To:

```
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/hosts
...
cfg_dir=/etc/nagiosql/services
```

***EDIT:***

Okay I think directory permissions may be causing the `cfg_dir` evaulations to fail.  According to the `ls -alh` output you listed, your `/etc/nagiosql/hosts/`, `/etc/nagiosql/services/`, and `/etc/nagiosql/` directories do not grant **write** permissions to the `nagios` group.  Nagios will need to get a directory listing for those directories and will need group write permissions to do it.

To remedy:

```
chmod g+w /etc/nagiosql/hosts/
chmod g+w /etc/nagiosql/services/
```

Restart nagios service.

Also, you don't need to remove the slashes from the directory paths in the nagios `cfg_dir` configurations.  Nagios will strip the trailing slash (`/`) for you, according to the code:

> https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/eb8e83d5d05e572eb8c0d4d4764885c5427b4b69/xdata/xodtemplate.c#L327

```
    /* process all files in a config directory */       else if(!strcmp(var, "xodtemplate_config_dir") || !strcmp(var, "cfg_dir")) {

        if(config_base_dir != NULL && val[0] != '/') {
            asprintf(&cfgfile, "%s/%s", config_base_dir, val);
            }           else
            cfgfile = strdup(val);

        /* strip trailing / if necessary */             if(cfgfile != NULL && cfgfile[strlen(cfgfile) - 1] == '/')
            cfgfile[strlen(cfgfile) - 1] = '\x0';

        /* process the config directory... */           result = xodtemplate_process_config_dir(cfgfile, options);

        my_free(cfgfile);

        /* if there was an error processing the config file, break out of loop */           if(result == ERROR)
            break;          }       }
```

**EDIT #2:** In the host definition you posted, your `register` value is set to `0`.  Try setting it to `1` instead.  `register 0` is used for templates that will be inherited from, but will not actually show up in the Nagios UI.

Change:

```
define host {
        host_name                       GIT
        alias                           GIT Server
        address                         172.25.10.80
        register                        0
}
```

To:

```
define host {
        host_name                       GIT
        alias                           GIT Server
        address                         172.25.10.80
        register                        1
}
```

Also please set `register 1` for your service definitions as well.

Comment: **slashes** removed from all `cfg_dir` definitions - but problem still exists

Comment: Ok, I think the real problem is in your directory permissions.  Without write permissions on the services and hosts directory, nagios can't list the config files in each of those directories.  Updated answer with suggestions.

Comment: Should not be a problem with directory permissions:
 drwsrwsr-x    2 apache nagios  4096 Aug  7 10:46 services
 drwsrwsr-x    2 apache nagios  4096 Aug 11 07:35 hosts

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok, just had one more idea.  Try changing "register 0" to "register 1" in your host and service definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding executable permissions to your directories. Some programs and languages require +x permissions in order to actually open the directory.

If that doesn't work, temporarily set everything to 0777 permissions to see if the issue is permissions related at all.

You also have config problems even if you get that part working. Your host and service configs don't have a **use** directive in them, which points to a template that would have most of the default values. The **register** directive is implied as 1 unless you specifically set it to 0 for a template. See the object definitions docs if you need a reference: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html